# What's the best way to start ssh-agent with Cygwin?

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, cygwin

I'd like `ssh-agent` to be started when I start Cygwin, since I use ssh passthrough often.

I tried adding:

```
eval `ssh-agent.exe`
```

to my `.bashrc`, but any time I use `Alt-F2` to open a new terminal window, the `.bashrc` is run and hence new `ssh-agent`s are created which is undesirable and messes with the passthrough.

I then tried moving the eval command to `.bash_profile`, but this too results in the same problem - I guess every new terminal window is considered a new login shell.

A third option is to use `cygrunsrv`, but I just found about it and am not clear on how to use it for this specific purpose, and perhaps more importantly, how to pass on the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` information from where the service is created to every new shell created.

Any suggestions on the best way to achieve this outcome - where a single ssh-agent is executed and waiting, and its information is immediately available to be used in any newly opened shell - is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in your `.bashrc`, but before starting it again you should check if it is already running.  For example, you can do

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    (umask 077; ssh-agent > "$HOME/.ssh/environment")
    ssh-add
fi
```

as part of the process.

```
Also, if the agent is not running, you could first test if that environment file exists and source it like

environ="$HOME/.ssh/environment"
if [ -f "$environ" ]; then
    . "$environ" >/dev/null
fi

if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || ! ps -p "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | grep -q ssh-agent; then
    (umask 077; ssh-agent > "$environ")
    ssh-add
fi
```

There's a lengthy answer detailing much of this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/109842) on the U&L site.

I do something like this, but have the `environ` file include the current hostname, since my home directory is on a network share and I want to run the agent on different hosts simultaneously.

And to call out explicitly how this answers your question about how to get the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable passed between processes, you store the output of `ssh-agent` in a file and source it again in each shell

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link. After looking at the various options, I went with the `keychain` solution, which turns out to be an awesome little program.